# how to let others could use my power auotomate flow?

Tags: office365, power-automate

For example, I create a flow with the 'when a new email arrives' trigger event, how to make this flow available to others？ I have shared the flow with the target user but it failed. I add the target user's outlook connection to the trigger event, it still doesn't work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Updated：**

I select the target user's outlook connection, then my mailbox will not trigger the flow. Since the action is bound to the personal account, only one person can use this flow. Is this right?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots or something showing the error(s) etc.?

Comment: No error is reported, just flow is not triggered.